# Automatically open source file on loading own project template in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been preparing for a coding competition, so I decided to make a VS project template in order to not be having to copy-pase the standard `include` statements into every new solution file.

After some research, I figured out how to get this done, however, there is one little thing that still bothers me. When loading the -standard- console application template, the source file is automatically opened. However, when creating a source file form my own template, I have to open the cpp source file manually the first time I am working on the code.

Is there any way I can change the template file such that my source file is automatically opened when starting a new project based upon this template?

I am using visual studio 2019

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the standard `include`s you would always use?

Comment: Just stuff like ```#include <vector>``` and ```#include <algorithm>```
I tried ```#include <bits/stc++.h>```, but sadly that doensn't work in visual studio.
It is not only the include statements, also (perhaps later when I am more advaced) some frequently used functions as well.

Comment: Oh dear, that is what I worried.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Haha, yes indeed, when I was looking why it didn't work, i found everybody saying 'dont do this'. Therefore, i decided to skip ```<bits/stc++.h>```, and use the libraries one at a time, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯